# Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

I was trying  to update grub config via Grub customizer, and it failed, and when I run update-grub2 I get this error
output of update-grub2: https://pastebin.com/AV6uZ2nv
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new: https://pastebin.com/VpaF4Epa

Comment: Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-customizer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.